# npm ERR while using run dev

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an error like this for a long time whenever I use npm run dev. how to solve it?

[image]

```
> tailwindcss@1.0.0 dev

> tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

> npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

I tried almost all possibilities using chatgpt

Comment: Consider look at the debug log that was printed with the error. This might give you some insight into the error. If you are unsure about what it might be telling you, consider editing your question to include the content of the log.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.